# How do I select parts from a model (Classes?)

Tags: r

I have fitted a model using caret.

I wanted to return a vector of just the variables used in the model.

here's a slimmed down version of `mymodel$terms`

```
mod_xgb$terms
cluster ~ patrol + investig + assault + alarm + vehicl + complaint + 
    properti + found + check + theft + suspici + activ + suspici_activ + 
    crimin + mischief
attr(,"variables")
list(cluster, patrol, investig, assault, alarm, vehicl, complaint, 
    properti, found, check, theft, suspici, activ, suspici_activ, 
    crimin, mischief
attr(,"factors")
                   patrol investig assault alarm vehicl complaint properti found check theft suspici activ suspici_activ crimin mischief
cluster                 0        0       0     0      0         0        0     0     0     0       0     0             0      0        0
patrol                  1        0       0     0      0         0        0     0     0     0       0     0             0      0        0
investig                0        1       0     0      0         0        0     0     0     0       0     0             0      0        0
assault                 0        0       1     0
attr(,"order")
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[68] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
attr(,"intercept")
[1] 1
attr(,"response")
[1] 1
attr(,".Environment")
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
attr(,"predvars")
list(cluster, patrol, investig, assault, alarm, vehicl, complaint, 
    properti, found, check, theft, suspici, activ, suspici_activ, 
    crimin, mischief
attr(,"dataClasses")
           cluster             patrol           investig            assault              alarm             vehicl          complaint 
          "factor"          "numeric"          "numeric"          "numeric"          "numeric"          "numeric"          "numeric" 
          properti              found              check              theft            suspici              activ      suspici_activ 
         "numeric"
```

Here is the str:

```
> str(mod_xgb$terms)
Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language cluster ~ patrol + investig + assault + alarm + vehicl + complaint + properti + found + check + theft + suspici +| __truncated__ ...
  ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(cluster, patrol, investig, assault, alarm, vehicl, complaint, properti, found, check, theft, suspici, activ,| __truncated__ ...
  ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:96, 1:95] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:96] "cluster" "patrol" "investig" "assault" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:95] "patrol" "investig" "assault" "alarm" ...
  ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:95] "patrol" "investig" "assault" "alarm" ...
  ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:95] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(cluster, patrol, investig, assault, alarm, vehicl, complaint, properti, found, check, theft, suspici, activ,| __truncated__ ...
  ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:96] "factor" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:96] "cluster" "patrol" "investig" "assault" ...
```

I don't understand how to subset this object. For example, in the str part above if I want to access the line for:

```
.. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:96] "cluster" "patrol" "investig" "assault" ...
```

To get the dimnames list, how do I subset this object?

Comment: Perhaps with `all.vars`

Comment: ```all.vars(mod_xgb$terms)```. Yes that worked thanks. I read ```?all.vars``` "Return a character vector containing all the names which occur in an expression or call.".  Thanks. More generally, is there a way to select objects from a class (this is a class object right?)